# OutOfMemoryError caused by multiple (>120) calls of getView in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, user-interface, out-of-memory

I am using a GridView to display images. The images are downloaded from a feed and added to a BitmapCache. The GridView is inside of a ViewFlipper (which has a ListView as second View). I'm using GridView for the first time but I've worked with Adapters many times when I used ListViews.

At the moment, the feed only delivers two images. But when I start my Fragment containing the GridView I get an OutOfMemoryError caused bei BitmapFactory.decodeStream(). When I took a deeper look into the logcat, I noticed that getView() inside of my Adapter for the GridView is called many many times. 
I know that it's nothing special if getView() is called more than once, but the getView()-method in my Adapter gets called over 120 times only for position 0. And I don't really understand why it's called so often. But I'm pretty sure that this caused my memory problem as this method tries to load a bitmap over 100 times in just a few seconds.

As I'm already trying to recycle my view with a ViewHolder I'm quite helpless at the moment and I hope somebody can explain me this massive calls of getView() and/or might give me a hint to solve my problem.

The getView()-mthod of my adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictures_grid_item, parent, false);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picturesGridImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
    }

    Picture picture = (Picture) pictureList.get(position);
    String imageUrl = picture.getUrl();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
        holder.image.setTag(imageUrl);
        ImageLoader.getInstance(context).loadImageWithTagCheck(holder.image);
    }

    return convertView;
}


private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
}
```

The *loadImageWithTagCheck()*-method just checks if the image has already been downloaded (which deffinitely should be the case)

The Fragment which holds the View:

```
public class PicturesFragment extends BaseFragment {

private List<Parcelable> pictureList;
private PicturesGridAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictures_fragment, container, false);
    // TODO: Remove final after development
    final MediaActivity activity = (MediaActivity) getActivity();

    pictureList = activity.getPictures();

    adapter = new PicturesGridAdapter(activity, pictureList);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.picturesGrid);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

BTW: I'm not using *wrap_content* anywhere.

Edit:
Here's the code of the imageloader. Ofcourse, the ImageLoader is the problem which causes the outOfMemoryError. But I think that the problem is rather something with the adapter because 120 calls of getView() for position 0 just after creating the view can't be right. And the Adapter is just created once so it's >120 calls in a single instance of my adapter.
(this is a pretty huge and complex project so the "simple" imageloader has a lot of code)

```
    public void loadImageWithTagCheck(final ImageView view) {
    final String url = (String) view.getTag();
    final Handler uiHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        }
    };
    if (imageHandler != null) {
        imageHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Bitmap bmp = getImage(url, view);
                uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String tagUrl = (String) view.getTag();
                        if (tagUrl.equals(url) && bmp != null
                                && !bmp.isRecycled()) {
                            scaleBitmapAndAdjustViewByHeight(view, bmp);
                        } else if (bmp != null) {
                            bmp.recycle();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

     private Bitmap getImage(String url, View v) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;

        if (url != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
            String md5Url = Utility.md5(url);
            if (cache.containsKey(md5Url)) {
                bmp = cache.getBitmap(md5Url);
            } else {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    URI uri = new URI(url);
                    httpGet.setURI(uri);
                    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        if (entity != null) {
                            final BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(
                                    entity.getContent(), Utils.IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
                            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                            options.outWidth = v.getWidth();
                            options.outHeight = v.getHeight();
                            options.inPurgeable = true;
                            options.inInputShareable = true;
                            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffIn, null,
                                    options);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (bmp != null) {
                    cache.put(md5Url, bmp);
                }
            }
        }

        return bmp;
    }

private void scaleBitmapAndAdjustViewByHeight(final ImageView view,
        final Bitmap bmp) {
    ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                        this);
            } else {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                        this);
            }

            // Get current dimensions
            int width = bmp.getWidth();
            int height = bmp.getHeight();

            // Determine how much to scale: the dimension requiring less
            // scaling is closer to the its side. This way the image always
            // stays inside your bounding box AND either x/y axis touches
            // it.
            int imageViewHeightFromXMLinPixels = view.getHeight();
            float xScale = (float) ((imageViewHeightFromXMLinPixels * 2.75) / width);
            float yScale = ((float) imageViewHeightFromXMLinPixels)
                    / height;
            float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

            // Create a matrix for the scaling and add the scaling data
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

            // Create a new bitmap
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width,
                    height, matrix, true);
            width = scaledBitmap.getWidth(); // re-use

            view.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
            view.getLayoutParams().width = width;
        }
    });
    view.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked through all of your code, but if you have a bitmap cache, why are you loading the same image more than once? Shouldn't you be reading it from the cache after the first time? Getting 120+ calls to `getView` for just position 0 sounds strange though.

Comment: I think you need to post the ImageLoader class too...

Comment: Thanks for your responses I added the code of imageloader.

@kabuko: The image is loaded only once. It uses the url as identifier so the code I originally posted just looked like it was loading more than once.

Comment: I just tried to to it without the ViewPager but I still have the same result. The only difference: getView() at position is _only_ called 90 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `scaleBitmapAndAdjustViewByHeight(...)` method.
Instead, do a simple `view.setImageBitmap(bmp)`.

Why?
`scaleBitmapAndAdjustViewByHeight(...)` calls `view.requestLayout()` which probably leads to calling your adapters `getView(...)` and ends in a deadlock and finally the OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Thanks! Your right, this was the problem. After commenting out 'view.requestLayout()' I only get 10 calls of 'getView()'. I didn't knew that every change to the views item invokes the 'getView' method. But now it all makes sense.